# How to get random to display properly in Windows Batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to make a little game in batch. I am using random to decide how much damage the player takes, then takes the final answer off the current health, then displaying the new health. However, rather than saying:

```
 Your HP:       %phealth%
```

it will say something like:

```
Your HP:       20-32764 * (1 - 0 + 1) / 32768 + 0
```

Here is the whole code so far:

```
@echo off
set phealth=20
set shealth=50
set pdamage=0
set sdamage=0
:start
cls
echo -----------------
echo Your HP:       %phealth%
echo Monster HP:    %shealth%
echo -----------------
echo You are wielding an iron dagger.
echo Choices:
echo --------
echo [1] Strike at the slime
echo [2] Back away
set /p choice=You choose option:
if '%choice%'=='1' goto :choice1
if '%choice%'=='2' goto :choice2
goto start

:choice1
cls
set pdamage=%random% * (5 - 1 + 1) / 32768 + 1
set phealth=%phealth%-%pdamage%
set sdamage=%random% * (8 - 2 + 1) / 32768 + 2
set shealth=%shealth%-%sdamage%
echo -----------------
echo Your HP:       %phealth%
echo Monster HP:    %shealth%
echo -----------------
echo You strike at the slime.
echo The slime strikes you back.
PAUSE
cls
goto start

:choice2
cls
set pdamage=%random% * (1 - 0 + 1) / 32768 + 0
set phealth=%phealth%-%pdamage%
echo -----------------
echo Your HP:       %phealth%
echo Monster HP:    %shealth%
echo -----------------
echo You back away.
echo The slime strikes at you.
echo You took %pdamage% damage.
echo The slime took 0 damage.
PAUSE
cls
goto start

:end
```

Comment: You say, "I am trying to make a little game in batch". Do you also beat yourself with chains?

Comment: @JohnSaunders  SNAKE.BAT - An arcade style game using pure batch http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4741

Comment: This is indeed only going to be a small text-based fight game, no imagery, maybe some flashing red when you are low on health.

Comment: well - sometimes it's more fun to ride a bicycle, even when there's a ferrari available...

Comment: @Stephan: I would at least ride a mountain bike, instead of a tricycle. There's this thing called PowerShell that's a lot more appropriate for complex scripting. "batch" is more of a punishment than a scripting language.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: some call it "punishment", others call it "challenge" - that's a matter of personal gust. And you can do nice tricks even with a tricycle. And yes, I agree - batch is everything but the best solution for this. But that's no reason to ridicule...

Comment: @Stephan: yes, it is reason to ridicule. I mean, why not write it in Assembler? That would be a challenge as well. Note that I'm not ridiculing the concept of writing games in scripting languages, or even "command shell" languages. But it would be a challenge to do it in PowerShell as well, and would also teach a useful tool with some very nice capabilities. Could you make use of remote execution, workflow, web access, running against multiple computers at once? "It's in there".

Comment: ah - so batch is not useful. Good to know... ^^. But seriously: "Q: I have a problem with my bike" "A: use a car" is not very helpful. More seriously: if you delete your comments, I'll delete mine. This would end in a open discussion

Answer (score 1):

To do arithmetics use `set /a`
for example:

```
set /a pdamage=%random% * (5 - 1 + 1) / 32768 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want random-in-a-range use `(%random% %% maxrange) + 1`

---

Demo:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
ECHO roll 6-sided 5 times
FOR /l %%x IN (1,1,5) DO CALL :roll 6
ECHO roll 4-sided 5 times
FOR /l %%x IN (1,1,5) DO CALL :roll 4
ECHO roll 1-sided 5 times
FOR /l %%x IN (1,1,5) DO CALL :roll 1
GOTO :EOF

:roll
SET /a result=(%RANDOM% %% %1) + 1
ECHO %result%
GOTO :EOF
```

Works for me!

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but as seen on my other batch question that always seemed to return 0.